# Setting the height of an absolutely positioned div to the height of its contents

Tags: jquery, css, html

Ok, I feel like this question has probably been asked before here, but after an hour of searching google I just cannot find the solution to this.

I have a div styled like this:

```
position: absolute;
height: 100px;
```

And when the contents of this div changes, I want to set the height of this div to the height of the contents of this div. I am using jQuery.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why not set it to relative and make the height auto ?

Comment: it needs to be `position:absolute` as this is how I am positioning the div

Comment: You don't need to set the height, it will be dynamic based on content if you leave it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
min-height: 100px;
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height

If for whatever reason you can't use that, or you want to do something else, you can get the height of the content of an element, regardless of the height of the actual element, using the `scrollHeight` property of a HTML element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight

In jQuery:

```
$(...).prop('scrollHeight')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
min-height: 100px;
```

instead of:

```
height: 100px;
```

Comment: Or you could leave out the `min-height` and `height` altogether. I don't see anywhere that the OP asked for a minimum height

Comment: What I understood from his post is that he wanted to have the DIV initially set at a height of 100px, and when the contents changed, have it resize its height to accommodate the contents. With min-height he'll be able to do so. However, I don't think it'll work for the cases where the content's height is less than 100px. In such cases, the DIV would remain at a minimum height of 100px.

Comment: That's my point, it's supposed to be dynamic if content grows or shrinks, therefore there's no reason to restrict its height.